# angular file uploader methods for http request

Tags: javascript, angular, file-upload

I'm trying to use angular-file-uploader and upload a file.
in afuConfig, I want to set method to **POST** but in terminal I have errors.

```html
uploadAPI:  {
      url:"https://example-file-upload-api",
      method:"POST",
      headers: {
     "Content-Type" : "text/plain;charset=UTF-8",
      },
}
```

it gives me this:

```html
  The types of 'uploadAPI.responseType' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"blob" | "json" | "arraybuffer" | "text" | undefined'.
```

I have the same problem for using responseType too.

Comment: in my case, I got this     "The types of 'uploadAPI.method' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"PUT" | "POST" | "PATCH" | undefined'. "

Answer (score 2):

The default `responseType` is `json`. Try to assign the `responseType: text` explicitly

```js
uploadAPI: {  
  url: "https://example-file-upload-api",
  method:"POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type" : "text/plain;charset=UTF-8",
  },
  responseType: 'text'
}
```

Comment: it didn't work for me.I think, it's a typeScript error but I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

try below code for headers:

```
httpOptions: {
  headers:{
    accept: 'application/pdf'
  }
  responseType: 'blob',
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me, it's more like typeScript error

Comment: Yes, I also got the same error, Which fields have predefined string values! Removing the attr fixes the issue but we cannot specify the value for those fields.